# Flash Builder / AIR: Can't export release build for AIR 2.0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I have an ActionScript only Flash Builder 4 project of which i know that it was successfully exported for AIR 2.0

If I set the the Flex SDK to 'Hero' and the required AIR version to 2.6 in the app-descriptor like here, then the export works fine:
[image: Flex Hero with 2.6]

However - if I change the Flex SDK to 4.0 (overlayed with the AIR 2.0.2 SDK) and change the version in the app-descriptor.xml to 2.0 like here:
[image: Flex 4.0 AIR 2.0 with 2.0]

then it will compile just fine and run in ADL, but it won't export. If i click the "Finish" button, the window only flashes for a moment but nothing happens. i can repeatedly click on finish, just a short flash, no error message, no exported air file.

If I leave the Flex SDK on 'Hero' and the only thing I do is to change 2.6 in the app-descriptor.xml to 2.0, then the same problem occurs!

I tried this with Flash Builder 4 as well as Flash Builder Burrito - in both cases the same problem.
Anyone an idea what goes wrong?

Comment: Which version is your AIR SDK? Look into Flex SDK folder, file AIR SDK Readme.txt.

Comment: i downloaded AIR SDK 2.0.2 and overlayed the Flex 4.0 SDK with it. the readme says 2.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app descriptor file is very different between 2.0 and 2.5 and above.  I'm surprised you're not seeing an error because I did (maybe try doing a clean?).  For instance, 2.5 supports profiles, instead of the `<version>` tag, it uses `<versionNumber>` and it also supports metadata for android/playbook OS'.

Comment: you're right - it was the wrong format. when i tried to compile the app with ADT i saw errors like versionNumber was not supported but version is required instead

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the application manifest XML for your air app and allowing flex builder to re-generate it. Sometimes these kinds of glitches happen because of errors with the application manifest.

Comment: by manifest XML you mean the app descriptor file? what do I have to do in order for flex builder to recrate it?

Comment: Yes I mean the descriptor. Flash builder should auto-generate it when you go to compile again.